# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: book is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I stuck with a problem, when I hit my route addBook then getting an error like book is not defined don't know where I am please try to fix my code. if you have any query on my code please let me know.

[image: Error page]

> route.js

This is the route.js file where I wrote my all logics

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Publisher = require('../model/Categary');
const Book = require('../model/Product');

// const {addCatogary} = require('../controllers/Product');
// router.get('/addcatogary',addCatogary);

router.post("/addPublisher", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //validate req.body data before saving
    const publisher = new Publisher(req.body);
    await publisher.save();
    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: publisher });
    console.log(publisher);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
  console.log(err);
  
});

router.post("/addBook", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //validate data as required

    const book = new Book(req.body);
    // book.publisher = publisher._id; <=== Assign user id from signed in publisher to publisher key
    await book.save();

    const publisher = await Publisher.findById({ _id: book.publisher });
    publisher.publishedBooks.push(book);
    await publisher.save();

    //return new book object, after saving it to Publisher
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: book });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
  console.log(book);
});

router.get("/publishers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await Publisher.find().populate({
      path: "booksPublished",
      select: "name publishYear author",
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
  console.log(data)
});

module.exports = router;
```

> Product.js

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = require('mongoose');

const bookSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   publishYear: Number,
   author: String,
   publisher: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Publisher',
      required: true
   }
},
{timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

> Catogary.js

This is the Catogary model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = require('mongoose');

const publisherSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   location: String
},
   {timestamps: true}
);

publisherSchema.virtual('booksPublished', {
   ref: 'Book', //The Model to use
   localField: '_id', //Find in Model, where localField 
   foreignField: 'publisher', // is equal to foreignField
});

// Set Object and Json property to true. Default is set to false
publisherSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
publisherSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Publisher', publisherSchema);
```

Comment: can you share the whole error instead of just error.message and also the body of the request you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post("/addBook", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //validate data as required

    const book = new Book(req.body);
    // book.publisher = publisher._id; <=== Assign user id from signed in publisher to publisher key
    await book.save();

    const publisher = await Publisher.findById({ _id: book.publisher });
    publisher.publishedBooks.push(book);
    await publisher.save();

    //return new book object, after saving it to Publisher
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: book });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
  console.log(book);
});
```

hey brother!
you have written a nice code but you have made a small mistake after catch block you are logging `book`  which is defined inside try block  and that `book` variable can not be accessed outside of that box because its local variable and can be only used inside try block
if you wanted to used that variable outside of `try{} catch(){}` block defined it with `var`

just check below link
[geeksforgeeks.org/global-and-local-variables-in-javascript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-and-local-variables-in-javascript/)

happy hacking :)